# How do function indexes work in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

Does anyone know how function indexes work in databases?

Comment: There is no such thing as a function index!  Are you talking about Searchable arguments?

Comment: I think he is talking about create index foo on table function(foo)

Comment: Mitch, WTF are you talking about>

Comment: you should really include a RDBMS in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about taking the result of a function when creating the index, this feature is used from SQL like this:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (function_name(column_name));
```

This can be used by the planner for queries like:

```
SELECT foo FROM table_name WHERE bar = function_name(column_name);
```

For exact details see the given RDBMS's documentation (for example in PostgreSQL it is called [indexes on expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html)).

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle there is something called **Function Based Indexes:**

Oracle 8i introduced Function Based Indexes to solve the following problem: **performing a function on an indexed column** in the where clause of a query guaranteed **an index would not be used**.

Here is a link:  [Function Based Indexes on Oracle-Base](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/FunctionBasedIndexes.php)

Comment: I don't know what "to slove" means.                                          Of course I do. I think you could tell his intent too. Busting on him for missing a word is not in keeping with SO Karma.

Comment: Mark, I'm sorry that my response looks offensive. I remember editing my answer. The original answer contained only the first two paragraphs and was meant to clarify his question.

Comment: Just for the record: I removed the first two paragraphs which could be  misunderstood.