# Varchar column case insensitive OpenJpa

Tags: openjpa

I have an entity (**Entity1**) with an id and an string as a unique fields:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "entity1_id")
    private long entity1_id;

    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String address;
```

There is a relation with another entity (**Entity2**) in this way:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "middle_table", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = entity2_id), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity1_id"))
    private List<Entity> entity1List= new ArrayList<Entity>();
```

FetchType is eager, so when I get an Object2 from the database, it comes with the complete list of Entity1.
The problem is that the `address` field is supposed to be in lowercase, but because of a migration problem, we have some cases where an address contains some capital letters. In those cases `Entity2.entity1List` array contains 1 object, which is null, because it can not be found in the database.
When the middle table is updated, I get this exception:

> ERROR: null value in column "entity1_id" violates not-null
>   constraint {prepstmnt 892492234 INSERT INTO
>   public.middle_table(entity2_id, entity1_id) VALUES
>   (?, ?) [params=?, ?]} [code=0, state=23502]

To make it clearer, let´s say that I have in the database: `Test@test.com`, but it should be as well identified as `test@test.com`.

**EDIT**

I have just realized that the whole explanation is not necessary. I can explain my problem in an easier way:
In my table I have an entry: `Test@test.com`. I wan this query:

```
select * from my_table where address = 'test@test.com'
```

To retrieve the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my table I have an entry: Test@test.com. I wan this query:
>
> ```
> select * from my_table where address = 'test@test.com'
> ```

Well, if you put it this way, you may as well restructure the query to:

```
select * from my_table where LOWER(address) = LOWER(:email)
```

For this query to be efficient, you'll need a [function-based index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/277447/838434) on your database — otherwise it's O(n) complex.